# How to replace a string in a variable that came from a CSV Data Config?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In my JMeter test plan, I have two CSV Data Config elements.

- CSV Data Config-element-requestBodies: This CSV Data Config element has a variable named "requestBody".  In the corresponding CSV file, each line has an XML request with a placeholder string.
- CSV Data Config-element-subject: variables.  This CSV Data Config element has a variable name "subjectDn".  In the corresponding CSV file, each line has a distinguished name (DN) for a user.

The "requestBody" variable will contain an XML request from the CSV file that has the request bodies, with a placeholder string and I want to replace that placeholder with the contents of the "subjectDn" variable, and then use the modified "requestBody" variable in the HTTP Request element.

In other words:

1. Replace the placeholder string in the ${requestBody} with the value in the ${subjectDn}, then
2. Use the modified ${requestBody} in the HTTP Request

How can I do that?  What is the easiest/least overhead way of doing that?

I've tried using the "__evalVar" function (see https://am.net/lib/tools/NetworkManagement/apache-jmeter-2.8/printable_docs/usermanual/functions.html), but it looks like that is not able to do the replacement when the string is from a CSV file?

Thanks in advance!

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `${requestBody}` into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval), it will allow JMeter to resolve [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are present as "placeholders" in the CSV file to their respective values.

```
${__eval(${requestBody})}
```

Also if you consider scripting to accomplish your requirements be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Dmitri - I had tried using __eval() before I was able to get the Beanshell pre-processor approach working.  When I tried the _eval() function, it did not work.  Specifically, even though the ${requestBody} has the var inside it, the inner var wasn't being evaluated/expanded, so I did the beanshell approach.  I don't particularly like having to use the beanshell (overkill!).  I googled after I saw your suggestion, and found this: https://groups.google.com/g/ptgram24/c/LfmtFQS5u_E?pli=1, and I may take a 2nd try with _eval() if I have time.  Thanks...

Comment: Dmitri - I just tried using __eval() again, and I was able to get it working!  I think that the problem that I had when I tried using __eval() earlier was because of the order of the CSV Data Set Config elements that were in the test plan.  This test, I ordered it was follows (config set for the request bodies, THEN config set for the subjectDn).  In the earlier test (which didn't work), I had those configs in the opposite order, i.e. (config set for the subjectDn, THEN config set for the request bodies), which WORKED!!!  Will mark your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this woring by using a Beanshell pre-processor and some Java code that does var.get() and then Java String replaceall() and then var.put().